# Can machine learning/AI lower the security existing cryptographic protocols similar to quantum computers?

Tags: provable-security, machine-learning

Initial thinking would be not unless the protocol revealed sensitive local information that could then be analysed by an ML algorithm and applied globally.

local meaning I see messages from Alice and Bob extract some information x,
then apply x to all other users.

Not an expert in ML, this was just initial thoughts.

Comment: This question appears to be extremely broad and discussion-based. What exactly is the question?

Comment: I would like to know if machine learning can be used to lower the security of our existing protocols. It is more specific than the question that seems to be a duplicate @EllaRose

Comment: Similar to how Quantum computers can lower the security using shors algorithm, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Machine learning and AI techniques do not fundamentally change the computational capabilities of an adversary like a quantum computer does, no matter how much hype is in the air around ML and AI.

Comment: Interesting. I thought it would maybe help with statistical based schemes like LWE. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends The statistical biases in modern cryptographic systems are so incredibly small that no conceivable ML algorithm would be able to detect it. Machine learning is all about pattern recognition, and cryptography is the very subject where patterns are intentionally avoided and destroyed.